# spring-quartz doesn't start with error message when try to start application?

Tags: java, spring, quartz

There is spring application deployed on websphere8.5.5.13

I try to use spring-quartz to schedule my jobs by cron, but they are start with error
My quartz configuration class

```
  @Configuration
    @Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
    @EnableScheduling
    public class ExportConfig {
        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;
        @Autowired
        private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
        @Getter
        @Autowired
        private MyService service;

        private final String QRTZ_TRIGGER = "My_TRIGGER";
        private final String QRTZ_GROUP = "My_GROUP";
        private final String QRTZ_JOB = "MyJOB";
        private final String TIME = "0 0-59 0-23 * * ?"; /* каждый час, каждые 0,15,30,45 минут */

        @Bean
        @DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
        public JobDetail cronJobMy() {
            JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(QRTZ_JOB, QRTZ_GROUP);
            return JobBuilder
                    .newJob(MyJob.class)
                    .storeDurably(true)
                    .requestRecovery(true)
                    .withIdentity(jobKey).build();
        }

        @Bean
        @DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
        public Trigger cronTriggerMy() {
            TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey(QRTZ_TRIGGER, QRTZ_GROUP);
            return TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(triggerKey)
                    .withSchedule(createSchedule(TIME)).build();
        }

        @Bean
        @DependsOn(value = {"entityManagerFactory", "dataSource"})
        public Scheduler cronSchedulerMy(JobDetail cronJobMy, Trigger cronTriggerMy) throws SchedulerException {
            StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory("quartzStandalone.properties");
            Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
            boolean triggerExist = scheduler.checkExists(cronTriggerMy.getKey());
            boolean jobExist = scheduler.checkExists(cronJobMy.getKey());

            if (triggerExist || jobExist) {
                scheduler.deleteJob(new JobKey(QRTZ_JOB, QRTZ_GROUP));
            }

            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.getContext().put("SERVICE", service);
            scheduler.scheduleJob(cronJobMy, cronTriggerMy);
            return scheduler;
        }

        private static ScheduleBuilder createSchedule(String cronExpression) {
            CronScheduleBuilder builder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression);
            return builder;
        }
    }
```

Job looks like this:

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
public class ExportJob implements Job {
    private static final String MESSAGE = "===================================EXPORT QUARTZ TACT===================================";
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, MESSAGE);
        try {
            ApplicationContext springContext =
                    WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getServletContext());
            Object bean = springContext.getBean("exportService");
            if (bean != null) {
                ExportService exportService = (ExportService) bean;
                exportService.export();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, "EXPORT_SERVICE_BY_QUARTZ Failed..");
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
    }
}
```

property-file

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MYAPPStandaloneScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = MYAPP
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
org.quartz.dataSource.MYAPP.jndiURL = java:comp/env/jdbc/MYAPP
```

my pom.xml

```
 <!-- Quartz for schedule -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

But, when try to start my application, there is error message

> 'MYAPPStandaloneScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'   Scheduler
>   class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.   NOT
>   STARTED.   Currently in standby mode.   Number of jobs executed: 0
>   Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1
>   threads.   Using job-store 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' -
>   which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
>
> [11/29/19 9:05:21:513 MSK] 00000109 SystemOut     O [2019-11-29
>   09:05:21.513] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      Quartz
>   scheduler 'MYAPPStandaloneScheduler' initialized from the specified
>   file : 'quartzStandalone.properties' from the class resource path.
>   [11/29/19 9:05:21:521 MSK] 00000109 SystemOut     O [2019-11-29
>   09:05:21.521] WARN  rt.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext Exception
>   encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh
>   attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'cronSchedulerExport' defined in class
>   path resource [quartz/ExportConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via
>   factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.quartz.Scheduler]: Factory method
>   'cronSchedulerExport' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create
>   delegate: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate [See
>   nested exception: pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cronSchedulerExport' defined in class path
>   resource [quartz/ExportConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.quartz.Scheduler]: Factory method
>   'cronSchedulerExport' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create
>   delegate: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate [See
>   nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     75)     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused
>   by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.quartz.Scheduler]: Factory method
>   'cronSchedulerExport' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create
>   delegate: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate [See
>   nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 76 more Caused by:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create
>   delegate: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate [See
>   nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate]   at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getDelegate(JobStoreSupport.java:3218)
>     ... 77 more Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate    at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1762)  at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getDelegate(JobStoreSupport.java:3213)
>     ... 96 more [11/29/19 9:05:21:537 MSK] 00000109 webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated
>   SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
>                                    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cronSchedulerExport' defined in class path
>   resource [quartz/ExportConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.quartz.Scheduler]: Factory method
>   'cronSchedulerExport' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create
>   delegate: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate [See
>   nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.quartz.Scheduler]: Factory method
>   'cronSchedulerExport' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create
>   delegate: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate [See
>   nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>     ... 76 more Caused by:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create
>   delegate: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate [See
>   nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate]   at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getDelegate(JobStoreSupport.java:3218)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.checkExists(JobStoreSupport.java:1988)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$23.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1981)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3864)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
>     at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeWithoutLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3800)
>     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.

```
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.NoSuchDelegateException: Couldn't create delegate:
```

The state of jobs is saved in _QRTZ - tables in database Oracle11g

Answer (score 1):

why not using spring-quartz starter ? you can use spring datasource rather than a dedicated datasource:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: password
  quartz:
    scheduler-name: quartzSchedulernot work anymore
    jobStore: jdbc
    startup-delay: PT10S
    wait-for-jobs-to-complete-on-shutdown: true
  properties:
    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
    org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export: true
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 15
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
    org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
    org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
    org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: QRTZ_
    org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
    org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval: 1000
```

you also have to remove your scheduler creation and let spring do it for you.